# autocomplete from list for individual words in a multiword text in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have an Excel Workbook containg multiple tables.
    One of the tables contains unique words, let's call them tags, all starting with a '#'.
I have to fill the cells in the other tables with free text, and I can append them with the tags specified in the first table.

I would like to have suggestions from the first table as I am typing a '#' and subsequent letters in a cell.

I have seen that it's possible to get suggestions as you're typing from a list with Data Validation. Is this also possible when the cell includes more than just the validated word? I yes, how would I go about it?

Comment: I don't think so. Is there any objection to let the tags particular to the text reside in a seperate column?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes: I would have to dynamically generate new colums because the number of tags to append is not fixed.Also, then all the cell contents (main cell, tag cells) would have to be combined into an extra cell.

Comment: You could just put all the tags in a single tag cell right? with a cell content of for example: "#Banana #Apple #Fruitbasket"

Comment: So its possible to have multiple words with autocompletion in the same cell? edit: I found a VBA snippet that does just that. I will play around with it!